# How to include AJAX in twig with Symfony 3

Tags: ajax, twig, symfony

I am working on a project with symfony 3 and I want to dynamically get a list of users from database by the name of the project they are working on.

This is the controller action:
[image]

This way it doesn't show anything, it only shows the first user if I write the action this way:
[image]

Comment: I'd first run the whole thing with a debugger, make a break point where you get your results and inspect what do you get in $pus.  If you can't run the debugger, just insert some var_dump($pus), right before the foreach. That will give you a clue of the problem.  It's hard to say without knowing your ProjectUser structure or if that findByName is actually a native repository function or something that you wrote. Anyway, what LeBlobb mentioned in his answer would be much more in line what is expected to do in Symfony - instead of generating the HTML inside the controller.

Comment: The problem was in the repository queries I fixed them but now the foreach loop doesn't return anything. any array built in a foreach is noted as undefined if I use it later outside of the loop.

Comment: That shouldn't be. Are you sure you are building the array properly, or even getting into that foreach? Do you have your error reporting turned on? Maybe something's going on that you don't see reported. Are you in Development or Production mode?

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand it right, you have a page where you have an AJAX request which shall return some data already rendered with twig.

What you need to do is:

1. One controller which returns normal HTML page
2. A second controller which returns your rendered data same as your first controller does, but this one uses a template which contains only the HTML which will be returned by the AJAX request.
3. In your AJAX request call the route defined in the second controller and display the result.

Example1:

ControllerOne.php:

```
class ControllerOne extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // show your page
        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

ControllerTwo.php:

```
class ControllerTwo extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("get/data/{userId}")
     * @param $userId
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function getDataAction($userId)
    {
        // get some data
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // this example shows retrieving user data
        // implement your logic for retrieving projecty by user id here
        $userData = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));

        return $this->render('user.data.html.twig', array('user' => $userData));
    }
}
```

index.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="application/javascript">

        // call the controller to get the rendered data
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get/data/1"
        })
                .done(function( data ) {
                    // insert data into div
                    $("#myDiv").html(data);
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

user.data.html.twig:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <!-- you have access to the data passed from controller here -->
        User name: {{user.name}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Example2:

JsonResponseController.php:

```
class JsonResponseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("get/data/{userId}")
     * @param $userId
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function getDataAction($userId)
    {
        // get some data
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // this example shows retrieving user data
        // implement your logic for retrieving projecty by user id here
        $userData = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));

        return new JsonResponse(array('userData' => $userData));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have another view to render I just want the first names of users to be shown in a <select></select>

Comment: Then you just have to return a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse in your action where you retrieving the  data: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response If that helps, ill adapt my answer so you can accept it

Comment: I have added another example

Comment: Thank you very much